# Download and parse in real-time ical files from TVMaze using PHP iCalendar

Tags: php

I have set up [PHP iCalendar](https://sourceforge.net/projects/phpicalendar/) and downloaded my ical file from [TVMaze](http://www.tvmaze.com/), but my question is; can I somehow use ical URL feed in PHP iCalendar, so that I have sort of live feed? I would think that those .ics files are pretty static and have to be downloaded with some regularity to keep events (tv shows) up to date?